# How to remove editText bold Span beyond a particular point in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am working on a text editor . I want to make text bold and normal(unbold) on a button click . When bold button has been pressed every next typed text is bold, but i am unable to make every next typed text normal once bold button has been unchecked .

```java
editText.getText().setSpan(boldSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

this line makes the every next typed text bold. i want to make text normal afterwards as soon as the bold button has been unchecked.

**what i have tried:**

I have tried setting `Typeface.NORMAL` on the coming text but this doesn't remove the boldSpan.

I have tried removing end part of the span , but this removes the whole span , so at the end no text is bold at all .

I have tried for days, trying different approaches , but none of them worked . Any approach to get my job done would be highly appreciated .

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: @Niceumang, sure .

Comment: have you look on RichEditor in android ?

Comment: It Provide various feature you dont need to set any code for bold,italic or normal

Comment: Please be specific and let me know only if you have an **answer** !

Answer (score 0):

check below code if its helpful for you.instead of string you can use your editText here dude ;)

```
String normalBefore= "First Part Not Bold ";
String normalBOLD=  "BOLD ";
String normalAfter= "rest not bold";
String finalString= normalBefore+normalBOLD+normalAfter;
Spannable sb = new SpannableString( finalString );
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), finalString.indexOf(normalBOLD)+ normalBOLD.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //bold
sb.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(intSize), finalString.indexOf(normalBOLD)+ normalBOLD.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: i appreciate you efforts, but that didn't work for me.i want to set the text bold while typing and do the converse the same way . Your approach seem to do these things if you already know what you are trying to make bold . this is not what i am looking for .